# Why Dokan Multivendor vendor's dashboard not load.?

Tags: wordpress

why woocommerce Dokan multivendor plugin  vendor's panel not loaded ?.
dokan Multivendor conflict .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the dashboard [Dokan usages the page](https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/settings/page-settings-2/) which you will be needing to configure from wp-admin → Dokan → Settings → Page Settings. Note that, the page must have this [dokan-dashboard] [shortcode.][2](https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/getting-started/installed-pages/) Make sure you have configured the page. If you have configured the page and still facing the error then you can contact the Dokan [technical support team.](https://wedevs.com/contact/) weDevs ( original author of the Dokan Multivendor) technical team will help you with the best possible solution.